# Why does my belly stick out so much when I am relaxed but have a six pack when I am flexing?

Tags: exercise, nutrition

[image].
I need help on figuring this out! Please [image]

Comment: See also https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/37432/relaxed-belly-no-abs-show

Comment: Second picture looks a bit like you've got some anterior pelvic tilt going on. Should be plenty of info out there on the web about it

Comment: Would that have much to do with my belly?

Comment: Yes, anterior pelvic tilt can make your abs look bloated when relaxed. Ask your doctor if you have it. If you don't  have anterior pelvic tilt you are fine and healthy

Comment: Ignore those comments, you very clearly have anterior pelvic tilt. It comes from an imbalance in muscle activity. Your pelvis is tilted backward because of this making your abdominals stick out. Look into this, 1 google image search will give you your exact posture problem.

Answer (score 11):

When you relax, all the fat is falling down to your lower belly, and stretching the skin out and away from abdominal muscles.

When you flex, the fat gets spread out over a larger surface area, showing the outline of what lies underneath.

This situation is true for a lot of people.

If you want your abs to show while relaxing, you need to lose some of that fat. But just so it's said; this is *only* beneficial from a vanity standpoint. From a health perspective, there is very little reason to desire a constantly visible sixpack.

As a sidenote, it's worth pointing out that you may have an anterior pelvic tilt, judging by your second picture. Is that something you're aware of?

Comment: Yeah but is there something wrong? I feel bloated constantly. I eat healthy like tuna, peanut butter, fish, chicken, Greek yogurt, veggies. I don’t need a visible 6 pack when i am relaxed but it sticks out so much and I want it to flatten a little bit. I do a large variety of body weight exercises every day and I try and do a HIIT exercise every night but it’s difficult to always do that.

Comment: @ryleemcneely how does anything in your comment relate to the problem? Just because someone told you those things are healthy and you work out a lot the universe doesn't grant you 3 wishes and a flat belly. We are human and we have flaws. If you don't earn money with your body you should maybe think ahead a bit. 50- 60 more years to live, better get a more healthy approach to fitness and set smarter goals than being scary-thin

Comment: It relates to the problem because I am trying to figure out if I am missing that key component. I am doing a lot to achieve MY goal but needed some input that would help. Everybody has their OWN goals, So you should rethink what you just said.

Comment: Nothing wrong with elaborating. To answer your question, @RyleeMcNeeley, feeling bloated doesn't mean you *are* bloated. You should experiment with your diet a little bit. The first thing that comes to mind is the tuna. While a great source of protein, it also tends to contain a lot of mercury, which can offset some of the body's natural processes. You don't mention how much tuna you eat, but I would consider replacing it with salmon.

Comment: @RyleeMcNeeley - As a sidenote, it's worth pointing out that you may have an anterior pelvic tilt, judging by your second picture. Is that something you're aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you still can read this. This is absolutely not normal. I have had this issue for three years. During these years I was trying to fix it, but I couldn't. Because of the bloating, I wasn't able to eat any food, I stopped two semesters from college, and quit my job. It started with bloating then hemorrhoids then finally gas and fecal incontinence. ONLY LAST WEEK (7 days ago) I figured out the solution to this problem. It was tight  hip flexors which will cause the abdominal stuff to stick out. You need to release your psoas and decompress your lumbar spine. Also strengthen your glutes and your actual abs! (Cause a lot of times we depend on psoas "lower back" during abs excersises). This is my experience and many has benefited from this. I just wish that more people will stop suffering from IBS and bloating.

Comment: Also, train your upper back (muscles just beside the upper spine). the more muscled your upper back is the flatter your stomach will be.